# How to create a new list of same type as old list in Java?

Tags: java, list, generics, clone

I'm trying to write a method that takes in a `List` and create a new `List` of the same type based on it. That is, if the input list is an `ArrayList`, then I want the method to create a new `ArrayList`. The problem is that the program won't know if the List is an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` until runtime.

So far I've tried using the `clone()` method, but I don't think it works because the List class doesn't have `clone()` defined, and when I cast the input list as an `Object` and then clone then recast as a List, it also doesn't work (I'm not sure why).

Comment: Can you say a bit about why you need to do this, rather than say simply always return a convenient list for known-length input lists?

Comment: As an aside, the Scala collection libraries do exactly this, by effectively adding an additional argument that is a builder of the type of list you want back.  The compiler does all of the heavy lifting (via "implicits"), and hides most of the details from the user of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you say more about why you want to do this?  Without a good rationale, I'd contend:

Consider not doing this at all, but instead:

```
static <T> List<T> cloneMyList(final List<T> source)
{
  return new ArrayList<T>(source);
}
```

If what you REALLY want is an efficient way to create a second copy of a known list, maybe the underlying implementation type really doesn't matter.  In that case, just use an `ArrayList` which can be efficiently allocated using the `List` copy constructor.

Comment: So the purpose of this is to have a method that can find the union of two Lists and return it as another List of the same type as the input Lists. That is if I put in LinkedLists, I want a LinkedList coming out. So I don't really need a second copy of a known list, what I do need is to initialize a list of the same type.

Comment: @crumbs: But WHY do you care that the return type is the same implementation type?  What would break if it were not?  And what if the two input lists are of different types (for instance)?

Comment: This is part of a class assignment, so it's really kind of arbitrary. There's no reason why I have to have the return type be the same as the implementation type, but it seemed proper to do so. Also, I've considered the different input type problem and just decided to base the return type off the first argument.

Comment: @crumbs357:  If it's arbitrary, suggest you simply write the method as `static <T> List<T> union(final List<T> left, final List<T> right)` and return whatever is the most efficient `List` implementation for your approach.  Anything else is asking the language/SDK something it explicitly tries to avoid doing.  Abstraction is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

All the standard lists from the JDK support clone, so

```
List copy = (List)((Cloneable)somelist).clone()
```

should work fine.

of course you can use reflection

```
Class c = somelist.getClass();
List newlist = (List)c.newInstance();
newlist.addAll(somelist);
```

Comment: No casting is needed for the reflection example. The newInstance() should return a child of a List

Comment: @tanyehzheng - type cast **is** required in the example as written.  Yes, newInstance() will return an instance of the expected class, but in the code as written the compiler only knows that it is Object or some subtype.  Now, if `c` was declared as a `Class<? extends List>` the typecast wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy - the `clone()` approach fails unless you cast the `List` to its actual class first.  The `clone()` method is not in the public API of `List` ... only in the standard collection classes that implement `List`.

Comment: @Stephen true, I've missed that the c is not generic.
@MeBigFatGuy You can straighaway use somelist.getClass().newInstance();

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: the `clone()` approach still fails

Comment: Your first code does not work. Cloneable does not have a public clone() method.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
List<YourType> destinationList = new ArrayList<>(sourceList.size());
Collections.copy(destinationList, sourceList);
```